# JavaFX: bindContent of TreeView selectedItems

Tags: javafx, binding, treeview, selecteditem

I want to bind a content of TreeView selected items list and bumped into a strange behaviour of the selected items change value when removing elements. I wrote a some test application:

```
public class TreeViewSelectedItemsBindingTest extends Application {

    public class Item extends TreeItem<Integer> {
        public Item(Integer... value) {
            Arrays.stream(value).forEach(v -> getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Integer>(v)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TreeView<Integer> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        treeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        treeView.setRoot(new Item(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
        treeView.getRoot().setExpanded(true);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        ListView<TreeItem<Integer>> listView = new ListView<>();

        Bindings.bindContent(listView.getItems(), treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

        treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
                .addListener((ListChangeListener<? super TreeItem<Integer>>) change -> {
                    System.out.println("Change: " + change);
                    System.out.println("TreeView size: " + treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size());
                    System.out.println("ListView size: " + listView.getItems().size());
                    System.out.println("-------------------");
                });

        HBox box = new HBox();
        box.getChildren().addAll(treeView, listView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This application bind `TreeView` selected items to `ListView` items. Select in the tree view all elements from 0 to 9 and then press `SHIFT`+element 5, for example, to change selection from 0 to 5 elements. You will got an exeption:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 9
```

It is because ListChangeListener.Change reports from index relative to initial unmodified list, not relative a list changed previously:

```
-------------------
Change: { [TreeItem [ value: 6 ]] removed at 6,  }
TreeView size: 9
ListView size: 9
-------------------
Change: { [TreeItem [ value: 7 ]] removed at 7,  }
TreeView size: 8
ListView size: 8
-------------------
```

You can see "removed at 6" then "removed at 7", but size of underlying lists also changed so index should not be increased here, i.e. all "removed at" should be at 6. And because of this a Bindings.bindContent is failed.

Comment: Good catch, but what is your actual question? This is pretty clearly a bug, and you should [file a bug report](http://bugs.java.com/), assuming one is not already filed for this.

Comment: I was not sure is this a bug or a known feature of TreeView. I will attempt to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug [JDK-8180359](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8180359). As a workaround the bonded list should be updated as whole:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(
    (ListChangeListener<? super TreeItem<Model>>) change -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                listView.setAll(change.getList().stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(i -> i.getValue())
                        .collect(toList()));
            }
        });
```